# React - What is the difference between stateless function component and common component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's the difference between stateless function component and common component when rending in React ?I couldn't understand very well! How can I get details about the difference between them! Thank you!

```
// Stateless function components  
const renderIcon = result => {
   return <a href={result.url} target="_blank"><Icon type="icon-fail"/></a>;
};

const Page = props => {
    // ...
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            {renderIcon(props.result)}
            ...
        </div>
   );
};


const ResultIcon = ({result}) => {
    return <a href={result.url} target="_blank"><Icon type="icon-success"/></a>;
};

const Page = props => {
// ...
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            <ResultIcon result={props.result} />
            ...
        </div>
    );
};
```

some codes I added some codes in project, there two methods to render component but perfect-scrollbar display differently. I don't know why!

```
    // parts of codes
const data = [...data] // ...some dates used
return <div className="parts_codes">
    {
        [
            {
                title: 'Table',
                components: [
                    {
                        dataType: 'basiclist',
                        DataComponent: ({mainTableData}, index) =>
                            <MainTable
                                loading={mainTableDataStatus}
                                // ...
                            />,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'String',
                components: [
                    {
                        dataType: 'Object',
                        DataComponent: ({type}, index) => (!type || status)
                            ?
                            <Spin key={index} />
                            :
                            <div key={index}>
                                <PlotComponent />
                            </div>
                    }, {
                        dataType: 'Object',
                        DataComponent: ({type}, index) => (!type || status)
                            ?
                            <Spin key={index} />
                            :
                            <div key={index}>
                                key={index}
                            >
                                <ColumnComponent />
                            </div>

                    }
                ]
            },
        ].map((item) => <div key={item.title} className="map_parts">
            <span>{item.title}</span>
            {
                item.components.map((details, index) => {
                    const {dataType, DataComponent} = details;
                    return <DataComponent index={index} data={data}/>       
// one component perferc-scrollbar instance failed
                    // return DataComponent(data, index);       
// another functional component perferc-scrollbar instance success
                })
            }
        </div>)
    }
</div>

class MainTable extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        // ... do perferc-scrollbar instance
    }

    render() {
        return <Table />
    }
}
```

Comment: `renderIcon(props.result)` is not a stateless functional component, it's simply a function which returns a component (which is totally valid, but not commonly used). `ResultIcon` in your example *is* a stateless functional component.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the difference between them in my example when they rendered ?I use perfect-scrollbar in componentDidUpdate,  but the perfect-scrollbar display differently in the two render method @Andy Ray

Comment: You're asking questions about code that we can't see and saying they're "different" without explanation. If that is your actual question, can you edit your question to reflect that with the necessary code?

Comment: I think I understand your question better. Can you show us with a picture how it is rendered in one vs the other? From just the code, those two look like they should render the same.

Comment: Other than the first icon being `icon-fail` and the second one being `icon-success` obviously.

Comment: I have added some codes    @jmathew

Comment: See edit to my answer

Comment: Overall your expected is right, I just don't undertand what is the difference of rendering process between 'DataComponent(data)' and <DataComponent data={data} />,if DataComponent is a component generating function. @jmathew

Comment: There's one extra function call per render() with `DataComponent(data)` so performance-wise its worse. That's the only difference as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

**After Question edit**

From the comments I gather your actual question is why is that exact snippet of code you provided failing.

It looks like this is the part you're having trouble with. Though I'm not sure. The comments around it are unclear. But I think it doesn't work as it is now.

```
item.components.map((details, index) => {
                    const {dataType, DataComponent} = details;
                    return <DataComponent index={index} data={data}/>       
// one component perferc-scrollbar instance failed
                    // return DataComponent(data, index);       
// another functional component perferc-scrollbar instance success
                })
```

`details.DataComponent` appears to be a component generating function. You could try just changing your `return <DataComponent...` to `return details.DataComponent({type: "Whatever type value is"}, index);`

However, that code seems to be mixing data and components. Overall I'm not sure what you're doing or trying to do but with my limited knowledge I'd expect something more like:

```
const DataComponent = ({type,index, status, data}) => {
    if(!type || status) {
        return <Spin key={index} />
    }
    else {
        // I assume plot component needs the 'data'
        return <div key={index}><PlotComponent data={data}/></div>
    }
}
```

Then each of your `DataComponent: () => ...` assignments would become: `data:"The data object for the graph"`.

And finally, your return statement in your inner map statement would be `return <DataComponent type={"Whatever type is"} status={"Whatever status is"} index={index} data={details.data} />;`.

**Old answer**

Those all are stateless functional components. Where did you hear of 'common components'? That's not a thing I've heard of. If you could provide some links to the material you are reading it would be helpful.

The other way of defining components is to inherit from `React.Component`:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
      }
}
```

Functional components, like the ones in your examples, are just a function; the same as would be in the `render()` of a component built with inheritance.

Regarding 'stateless': In programming, 'state' is a concept that refers to data that is carried over from one execution to the next. Stateless components don't carry any data. They can't because they are just a function not a class.

This makes them simpler but more predictable. Send the same parameters to the stateless component multiple times, you will get the same result.

This is more clear with examples. Many are provided [here in the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Answer (score -2):

basically we use **stateless** *functional Components* when we doesn't need to use a life cycle method and neither the state, so that's why it's called stateless(without state). So we do not need to inherit from React.Component class, all we need is to return **JSX** directly with props data.
I recommend that you take a look at the [react](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) docs.

Comment: for those who are down voting my response, you could write me a comment and prove that what i said is wrong ?